# invisible elements with layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make something like the one below. However for some reason, the buttons are invisible. Can anyone kindly help

```
--------------------
 txt1          txt2
--------------------
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|     txtview1     |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
--------------------
|btn1|        |btn2|
--------------------
```

layout code:

```
                        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
                    android:text="Network Status:     "/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="updating..."
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt1"/>

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/sv1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txt1">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt3"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:text="Log"/>

                </ScrollView>

                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Start"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/sv1"/>

                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Stop"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/sv1"/>


            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use a LinearLayout as a surrounding for your ScrollView...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the ScrollView fills the rest of the space. You can use the fill_parent attribute, but the ScrollView has to be **above** the buttons. So in ScrollView, set `layout_above` to one of the Buttons.

Comment: what i did was remove the `layout_below` from the buttons... thats it... and used  `alignParentBottom="true"`.. worked nicely... your explanation makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to use positioning attributes for your elements if you use a RelativeLayout

there will be options like `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_below="@id/yourelement`

Comment: well, if I give `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`then, i see the buttons but they are at the top. if i use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, the buttons are not visible!.. any advice ?

Comment: the scrollview being set to `fill_parent` is what is doing it. make the width fill parent but the height needs to be something else for now

Comment: Is it because your scroll view's height is set to "fill_parent"? try setting a size to the height of the scroll view.

 I think the buttons are there but underneath the scroll view